# How to enable maximize option in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: maximized

I installed Ubuntu 16.04 today. When I right click on title bar of any application maximize option is greyed out. How to enable it? I know It's a very basic problem but I did not find any solution yet.

Comment: Would you like to clarify What made you to down vote my question, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## GNOME Tweak Tool

Go to the all apps menu, and type in tweaks. This will take you to the GNOME Tweaks settings.

On the side panel select '**Windows**'. Under this tab there is a heading called. **Titlebar buttons**. You there can enable both maximize and minimize.

If you don't have gnome Tweaks installed simply go to your terminal and type in `sudo apt install gnome-tweak-tool` then follow the instructions above